# Cannot run crontab on Redhat

Tags: php, linux, cron, redhat

I have .sh file on redhat to run a crontab.
Content of this file

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "run every 1min..."
```

I run it with the command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# * * * * * /var/www/html/ac/bc/1.sh
bash: anaconda-ks.cfg: command not found
```

Comment: Why PHP is a tag here??

Answer (score 2):

The cron configuration rule is not a shell command (although it ends with one).

You have to enter it into your cron configuration, not enter it at the command prompt.

Run `crontab -e` to edit your cron configuration.

Comment: Thanks you, i run "crontab -e" and write "* * * * * /var/www/html/ac/bc/1.sh", but i can save it. Sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 1):

type

```
  crontab -e
```

press i

paste the line

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/ac/bc/1.sh
```

next save crontab

press

```
esc
```

type

```
:wq!
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `crontab -e` then type your cron command.
Then to save it press `ESC` and then press `wq` followed by `enter`.. Done.